# Oozie workflow id generation

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

Is is possible to know the workflow id of the next oozie job that gets generated?
When oozie is restarted, its hard to know the next oozie workflow id. Any way to get it guys?

Thanks,

Vishnu Ganth

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: Came across this source code. Hope it helps to understand the logic. https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/f1e01a9e155692aa5632f4573ab1b3ebeab7ef45/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/service/UUIDService.java#L117

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's a way to know the next id that get's generated.

The best thing you could do is control the name that's being set by the oozie job for your application.

Have an application tracker job, that submits other oozie REST jobs. Whenever it submits a REST job, you can get the oozie jobID that you could store.

For example, if you are using OozieClient class in java - 
String jobId = client.run(conf);

This way, you can at least keep a track of all the applications you are generating?